# Leftover files after making a commit involving "moved" files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

When I rename or move files in my Git repository, these are shown in the unstaged file list in SourceTree as two entries - a "new file" and a "deleted file". Once I stage both of these ('Add to Index' and 'Remove', respectively), it appears in the staged files list as a move with an arrow icon. This is great so far, and I then select that file with the arrow icon and "Commit Selected".

I enter a message and "Commit", but now all the deleted files are still hanging around uncommitted. The commit shows that all the newly-added files were committed just fine, but the deleted ones have somehow been left behind.

I'm sure I could find a solution for this with Git on the console, but I like to use SourceTree and don't want to have to switch back to the console for commits of this nature.

Is there perhaps a setting I have missed? Is this just a bug?

Comment: If one day you do end up using the terminal, the correct way to do this is via the command `git mv` and `git rm`. Also, I can't recreate your problem with SourceTree. I renamed a file, added it and it's deleted file, SourceTree recognized it and the old file is no longer in the folder

Comment: I also tried creating a fresh local repo, adding a file and then renaming it with appropriate commits and it works just fine. Something in my real repo must have gone wrong. It'll be hard to track down unless someone has had a similar problem and recognises the symptoms.

Comment: I do this all the time with SourceTree and I haven't seen this issue before.

Comment: @HBHB `git mv` is just a wrapper around a standard `mv` followed by `git add` and `git remove`.  There is nothing more "correct" about it than what SourceTree does when staging the files.

Comment: I had a similiar problem. the latest update solved it